# Android Main Activity Object Access

Tags: android

Im new to Android and got a problem. I wanted to seperate the OnClickListener from the MainActivity class but I don't know how to access the Objects in the Main Activity class except of using static. Would be happy about a solution.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

public Button btn;
public TextView tv;
public MyListener listener;

public MainActivity() {
    this.listener = new MyListener();
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    this.btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);    
    this.tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    this.btn.setOnClickListener(listener);




}
}


public class MyListener implements OnClickListener {

MainActivity activity;
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    activity.tv.setText("Hi");

}
}
```

Doesnt work.
I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I think java doesn't allow two public classes in a single file

Comment: why do you want it to be separate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would want them separated like that.

If you don't want to cram the `onCreate` method of your activity, just implement the listener in your class like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    ...
}
```

Then reference the listener with `this`:

```
this.btn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. MainActivity is a Activity class. You should not have constructors for the same. You should not instantiate a activity class. You only declare activities in manifest file
2. You can have `this.listener = new MyListener();` in `onCreate` itself
3. Make `MyListener` an inner class of `MainActivity`